# using the Logger with DASK Futures

Tags: logging, dask

I have been trying to send log information from within a Dask Futures operation to a separate file.  Normal implementation without using Dask works fine.  Then, within the code that is sent to DASK, the logs don't seem to go anywhere.  I have also tried modifying the *.yaml file that multiple people have referenced.  However, that doesn't seem to change the way it is operating.  Any help, with some example code, would be great on how to use the logging capability while also using DASK.

Comment: If you are printing/logging from a function these should be available in the dask worker logs.  This has come up a few times https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/5577 and https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/2033 one of the issues has yet to be resolved but perhaps we could improve documentation around this as well ?

Answer (score 0):

@quasiben's comment should be posted as a potential answer:

> If you are printing/logging from a function these should be available
>   in the dask worker logs. This has come up a few times
>   [dask/#5577](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/5577) and
>   [distributed/#2033](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/2033) one of the issues has yet to
>   be resolved but perhaps we could improve documentation around this as
>   well.

I would also add: the question doesn't specify whether it is Dask's own logging or their own which they wish to see, how the logging is being used, or where they are trying to find the output. For example, if you had your own logger in your code, with a handler which is set to write to a file, then you would expect to find the output in the given file on the machine where the code executes.