# how to set up proper printout destination for dask multiprocessing in jupyter notebook on linux

Tags: printing, output, jupyter, dask

I am using dask in jupyter notebook on a linux server to run python functions on multiple CPUs. The python functions have standard print statement. I would like the output of the print to be shown in the jupyter notebook right below the cell. However, the print out were all shown in the console. Can anyone explain why this happens and how to make dask.function.print output to the notebook, or both the console and the notebook.

The following is a simplified version of the problem:

```py
import dask 
import functools 
from dask import compute, delayed 
iter_list=[0,1] 

def iFunc(item): 
    print('Meme',item)
# call this function itself will print normally to the 
# notebook below the cell, desired. 

with dask.config.set(scheduler='processes',num_workers=2): 
    func1=functools.partial(iFunc) 
    ret=compute([delayed(func1)(item) for item in iter_list]) 
# surprisingly, Meme 0, Meme 1 only print out to the console,
# not the notebook, Not desired, hard to debug. Any clue?
```

Comment: The following is a simplified version of the problem:
import dask
import functools
from dask import compute, delayed

iter_list=[0,1]
def iFunc(item):
    print('Meme',item)#call this function itself will print normally to the notebook below the cell, desired.
    
with dask.config.set(scheduler='processes',num_workers=2):
    f_par=functools.partial(iFunc)
    ret=compute([delayed(f_par)(item) for item in iter_list]) #surprisingly, Meme 1, Meme 2 only prints out to the console, not the notebook, Not desired, hard to debug. Any clue?

Comment: The code snippet you've provided prints the output in the notebook for me. Are you actually spinning up your workers using the terminal? If so, that's a critical part of your [mre]. If this block does print standard out to a random terminal that's not running a dask worker, that would be very strange indeed and maybe even a bug report if you could make it reproducible.

Comment: I ran the code from jupyter notebook at Linux server. The print out only goes to the terminal that I started the jupyter notebook, not t the notebook cell. Weird.

Comment: Then I tried to run the same code at a basic aws server as a test. It prints to both terminal and notebook cell. Very confusing. Is there a parameter somewhere in dask.config to manage this? Thanks.

Comment: No there isn't - see the discussion in the issue/pull request I referenced in my answer

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of dask is leveraging multiple threads, processes, or nodes/machines to distribute work. The workers you create are therefore not on the same thread as your client, and may not be on the same process, or even the same machine (or like, in the same country) as your client, depending on how you set up your cluster.

If you start a LocalCluster from your jupyter notebook, whether you're using threads or processes, you should see printed output appearing as output in the cells which execute jobs on the workers:

```py
In [1]: import dask.distributed as dd

In [2]: client = dd.Client(processes=4)

In [3]: def job():
   ...:     print("hello from a worker!")

In [4]: client.submit(job).result()
hello from a worker!
```

However, if a different process is spinning up your workers, it is up to that process to decide how to handle stdout. So if you're spinning up workers using the jupyterlab terminal, stdout will appear there. If you're spinning up workers in a kubernetes pod, stdout will appear in the worker logs. Dask doesn't actively manage standard out, so it's up to you to handle this. Note that this also applies to logging - [neither stdout nor logs are captured by dask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635279/using-the-logger-with-dask-futures). This is actually a really important design feature - many distributed systems have their own systems for managing the standard out & logging of nodes, and dask does not want to impose its own parallel/conflicting system for handling output. The main focus of dask is executing the *tasks*, not managing a distributed logging system.

That said, dask does have the infrastructure for passing around messages, and this is something the package could support. There is an open [issue](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/2033) and [pull request](https://github.com/dask/distributed/pull/4502) attempting to add this ability as a feature, but it looks like there are a lot of open design questions that would need to be resolved before this could be added. Many of them revolve around the issues I raised above - how to add a clean distributed logging feature without overburdening the scheduler, complicating the already complex set of configuration options, or overriding the important, existing logging systems users rely on. The dask core team seems to agree that this is a good idea, if the tough design questions can be resolved.

You certainly always have the option of *returning* messages. For example, the following would work:

```py
In [10]: def job():
    ...:     return_blob = {"diagnostics": {}, "messages": [], "return_val": None}
    ...:     start = time.time()
    ...:     return_blob["diagnostics"]["start"] = start
    ...:
    ...:     try:
    ...:         return_blob["messages"].append("raising error")
    ...:         # this causes a DivideByZeroError
    ...:         return_blob["return_val"] = 1 / 0
    ...:     except Exception as e:
    ...:         return_blob["diagnostics"]["error"] = e
    ...:
    ...:     return_blob["diagnostics"]["end"] = time.time()
    ...:     return return_blob
    ...:

In [11]: client.submit(job).result()
Out[11]:
{'diagnostics': {'start': 1644091274.738912,
  'error': ZeroDivisionError('division by zero'),
  'end': 1644091274.7389162},
 'messages': ['raising error'],
 'return_val': None}
```

Comment: Very detailed. Thanks.